# .NET MVC Routing works, except for one piece

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Little help here and advice.

Working on my first MVC application and I've got an entity of Students setup.
Student Controller and views with basic CRUD capabilities. 
mysite.com/Student gets me there.

Now I want to add Payments, so I've added a Payments controller and views with basic crud.
that gives me mysite.com/Payments

I want payments to go a URL that looks like:  mysite.com/Student/Payments

So I researched URL routing and (I think) I had it backwards for a long time as nothing seemed to work.  But now, I've created this additional Route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Payments",
            "Student/Payments/{action}/{id}",
            new { Controller = "Payments", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

And now it all seems to work properly.  When I send an ActionLink to any action in the Payment controller, the URL is correct.  For example: www.mysite.com/Student/Payments/Edit/5  comes up as the URL.

The problem I'm having is that Payments is still a base URL route.  So I can also get to payments by going to www.mysite.com/Payments

How do I "remove" that route, so that mysite.com/Payments is not valid?  Or am I doing this all ass-backwards in some way?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your kind of thinking about it the wring way around. The mapping configuration just supplies a hierachical list of rule to specify where a particular url's code lives.

So when you say it's still hitting mysite.com/Payments. That's because it's hitting the default rule in your Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

You could remove this but then no default rules will work.

or you can add an ignore rule. In your case something like

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("Payments/{action}/{id}");
```

make sure you put this above the default rule.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use overload of MapRoute method for your default route i.e.:

```
routes.MapRoute(  
  "Default",  
  "{controller}/{action}/{id}",  
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
  new { controller = ""}); //there constraints for controller goes
```

Look at [this blog post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx) about creating custom constraints, there is example for "not equals"